# Functions unbounded at a point on the domain: How to show electric field exists for any continuous volume charge density?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, singularities, coulombs-law

> **My understanding after reading Mike Stone's answer:**
>
> \begin{align}
> \vec{E} &= k \iiint_{V} \dfrac{\rho(x',y',z')[x-x'\hat{(i)}+y-y'\hat{(j)}+z-z'\hat{(k)}]}{[(x-x')^{2}+(y-y')^{2}+(z-z')^{2}]^{3/2}}dx'dy'dz'\\
> &= k \iiint_{V} \dfrac{\rho\ (\hat{r})}{r^2}dV\\
> &=k \iiint_{V} \dfrac{\rho\ (\hat{r})}{r^2} r^2\ \sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi\\
> &=k \iiint_{V} \rho\ (\hat{r}) \sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi\\
> \end{align}
>
> Now our function is $\rho\ (\hat{r}) \sin\theta$.
>
> $\hat{r}$ and $\theta$ are undefined only at the origin. Therefore our function $\rho\ (\hat{r}) \sin\theta$ is undefined only at the origin. **So we cannot directly integrate it. Hence we have to use the limit approach**:
>
> \begin{align}
> \vec{E} &= \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\ k
> \left( \iiint_{V \setminus\ \text{sphere with radius $\epsilon$ centered at origin}} \rho\ (\hat{r}) \sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi     \right)\\
> &-\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\ k
> \left(\iiint_{\text{over a sphere with radius $\epsilon$ centered at origin}} \rho\ (\hat{r}) \sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi \right)
> \end{align}
>
> In the first term $\rho, \hat{r} \text{ and } \theta$ is defined and finite everywhere. Therefore the integral in the first term is finite.
>
> Since the radius of the sphere $(\epsilon)$ is approaching zero, $\rho$ becomes more and more constant and the second term approaches zero.
>
> Hence:
>
> \begin{align}
> \vec{E} = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\ k
> \left( \iiint_{V \setminus\ \text{sphere with radius $\epsilon$ centered at origin}} \rho\ (\hat{r}) \sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi     \right)=\text{finite}
> \end{align}
>
> *However I do not know how to proceed to further simplify this term*.

Comment: `we use the limit method` as written, both limits in the sum $(2)$ are still infinite. I think you actually meant the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), which is a limit of a sum, not sum of limits.

Comment: Both limits in the sum $(2)$ are infinite....Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, just evaluate them one by one, you'll get infinities. After that there's no sense in which they could be added.

Comment: @Ruslan: Please have a look at my edited question.

Comment: We _can_ directly integrate it. Integration is insensitive to removable singularities. See e.g. [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240053/64206). And note that if your $r^{-2}$ was canceled by $r^2$, and the integrand is no longer unbounded, then you indeed have a removable singularity at the origin.

Comment: @Ruslan: If we are considering surface charge density, will then $r^{2}$ in the denominator and $r^2$ in $r^{2}\ \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi$ cancel out resulting in a removable singularity?

Comment: Well, if the only "problem" of your function is that it's undefined (or is discontinuous) at a point where a finite limit exists, it's _by definition_ a removable singularity.

Comment: @Ruslan: I understand your point. However I mean in case of a surface charge density $\sigma$ over an arbitrary surface $(A)$, then, just as we did in the $3-$dimensional case, can we cancel $r^2$ $\left (\text{in } \dfrac{\sigma\ (\hat{r})}{r^2}\right)$ and $r^2$ $\left( \text{in } dA=r^2\ \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi \right)$?

Comment: Can you think of any argument to not be able to cancel them? If you've correctly derived the form of your integral in spherical coordinates, then all rules of algebra still apply. I'm not sure what your doubt is.

Comment: No argument comes to my mind.. I just wanted to make sure that it is indeed the case.

Answer (score 2):

The element of volume in 3d is $dV= r^2dr d\Omega$ where $d\Omega= \sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ is the angular part. Put the origin of your coordinate system at the point where you want to compute the field. Observe then, that the $r^2$ overcomes the $1/r^2$ divergence in the $\hat {\bf r}/|{|{\bf r}|^2}$ integrand (here $\hat {\bf r}$ is the  unit vector). The field therefore remains finite provided  the charge density remains finite. Of course if there are point charges the field diverges-so not **any**  charge density works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Anyway in what direction should $\hat{r}$ point at the origin?

Comment: Won't $\hat{r}$ be ambiguous at the origin? How shall we deal with it?

Comment: @faheemahmed400. There is no ambiguity because there is no contribution at the origin. Think of a small sphere of charge density $\rho$. The ${\bf E}$ field  at a distance $r$ from the center of the sphere is ${\bf E}= \rho {\bf r}/(3\epsilon_0)$. This is zero at the center of the sphere. Your entire integral is a sum of the contributions from each sphere.

Comment: Your answer and comment were very useful. As a finishing touch, please have a look at my edited question and ensure whether I am understanding things the right way.